How do you show the interstitial on a Sabre Desktop only app?
In a web based sabre app its possible to call the Interstitial service which will show a loading circle during a long running task. The method to do this is found here:
https://developer.sabre.com/sdks/travel-agency/sabre-red-360/help?page=interstitialservice

This same screen appears when the desktop version is loading. However I would like to use it in my Desktop Red App which has a long running operation. Does anyone know how to get this or something similar working on a desktop only Red App?
